# R - Create a loop to calculate the length and Sum of a column where Identifier equals value in list

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops

I am attempting to create a loop to calculate the length and average value of a column where the identifier equals the value in a list. I basically have a dataframe with a Identifier, number of occurrences, and additional data. I also have a list that contains the unique of the identifiers (50 string values). I want to summarize the number of rows and average value for each of those 50 values.

So far I've tried creating two functions to calculate those values, and then integrating it into the loop but have been unsuccessful.

```
infoAvg = function(x){
average = mean(x)
return(average)}

infoLen = function(x){
length = length(x)
return(length)
}
```

Here x is the DF and y is the column I want to calculate on.

Does it make sense to take this approach, and if so how do I integrate it into a loop?

Thanks.

Comment: No, there are several fundamental problems here. Firstly, this is a function, not a loop (these are two different things). Secondly, your function body is not wrapped in curly brackets, so only the first line is stored as the function. Thirdly, if `y` is a column name, it won't be found inside the function, since you need to tell the function that y is a column in x. Fourth, you can only `return` once from a function. If you want both objects returned from a function, you need to put them in a `list`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've changed course slightly since posting this question, part of which addressed your comment. Currently I am attempting to have the two functions above apply to a column in a df where the ID equals a specific value. My hope is to create a loop where these two functions are applied to every value in my separate list of 50 strings (which is unique list of the identifiers in the df).

Comment: But now your functions don't really do anything. `infoAvg(x)` is just doing the same as `mean(x)` and `infoLen(x)` is just the same as `length(x)`

Comment: That does make sense. Is there a way to apply length(x) and mean(x) to my dataframe but for each value in the list? I am really just trying to create a loop that applies length and mean for each value of my list

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it's difficult to give you working code, but essentially you need something like `library(tidyverse); df %>% group_by(identifier_col) %>% summarize(infomean = mean(value), infolen = n())`. This will give you a data frame with every unique value of `identifier_col` in its own column, a column with the average value of the `value` column for each value of the identifier, and a column giving the number of rows containing that identifier. No need for loops, or to write your own functions.